# Modify x- y- coordinates by hand (RD)

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I am new with QGIS. I know how to generate the x and y coordinates by using the field calculator ($x, $y). I know these are just static values. What I want to do is to change the coordinates by hand so that the values are actually changed.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What does the abbreviation of RD which is used in your title stand for?

Comment: @PolyGeo: considering his Dutch-sounding name I suspect he is using "Rijksdriehoek", the local projection used in the Netherlands. Shouldn't matter for the question though.

Answer (score 7):

1. on the QGIS toolbar, click edit mode-pencil
2. on the toolbar, activate the edit nodes button
3. select the point you want to edit with a mouse click
4. in the Vertex Editor panel, change the coordinates manually, with respect

Comment: that does the job, thank you very much. Indeed RD stands for our local projection "RijksDriehoek". Did not know if that was usefull.