# How can I update position of points with coordinates?

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table, coordinates, expression

I have the following use case: I have around 1000 points and their positions in the attribute table. Sometimes I get an email with an updated position (coordinates) of a certain point. The problem is, when I update the position in the attribute table, the point in the map doesn't change. I know, that is just the way how GIS works. I also know I could go into editing mode, use the advanced editing toolbar and copy & paste the new coordinates for the point. But this is a bit too much work because it is a repetitive task.

What would be an easier way to update the position of a point with using coordinates?

From a user perspective it would be great to just copy & paste the new coordinates in the attribute table and the position of the point would update to the new position. I know that doesn't work, but maybe I could realize it with an expression in the attribute formular.

Do you have an idea which expression I could use?

Answer (score 4):

I just found out, I could use the vertex tool of the editing toolbar:

1. acitivate the editing mode.
2. activate the vertex-editing-mode
3. right-click on the point
4. insert the new coordinates

[image]

Comment: You could also use a CSV layer. Whenever you update the CSV file, then next time you open the project, the points will be moved.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/282903/120129

Comment: @wingnut: I didn't know that, amazing! I tested it, it works perfectly.

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko: thanks! I didn't find that post before I posted my question.

Comment: it turns out that this is a duplicate...

Comment: Should I delete this post? I get a warning...

Comment: To add to the solutions: if you need the updated postion for visual purposes only, you could use QGIS expressions: change your symbol layer style to `geoemtry generator / point` and add this expression: `make_point (x,y)`, where `x` and `y` are the attribute names of x- and y-coordinates.

Comment: I think you can add your answer to the old question (you have it with a picture), and delete your new question and new answer, otherwise the old and new question and answer duplicate each other...